# Safari skipping 5 seconds into react-player video - anyone have experience with this?

Tags: video, safari, react-player

I've built a component with react-player. It works as expected on Chrome, and most of the time on Safari, but there is one video that starts 5 seconds into the video when I click play. The same component as all the other videos, but only this one video skips in.

The part it skips into is a close up talking shot - could it detect the face and skip in to that part?

This is the react-player:

```
<ReactPlayer
                    url={media.filename}
                    width="100%"
                    height="100%"
                    playing={isPlaying}
                    loop
                    muted={autoplay ? true : false}
                    controls={playerState !== 'initial'}
                    onPause={() => setPlayerState('paused')}
                    onStart={() => setPlayerState('playing')}
                    light={thumbnail ? thumbnail.filename : false}
                />
```

I tried using a different file for the video, didn't work. I tried using seekTo but couldn't get it to recognise the player useRef and I don't think that helps me understand why the issue is happening

Comment: _"There is one video that starts 5 seconds into the video when I click play"_ You should mention the format of the video where possible, since it might help sometimes. Is that `url={media.filename}` testing an `.mp4` file by any chance? If yes, then the file might have an **edit list** which makes it skip. Other causes can be corrupt timestamps, or else the player itself skipping some unplayable corrupt frames (and so it starts picture at 5 seconds)